# Automatic reordering of citations in Word 2013 IEEE style

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2013

I'm currently working on my physics report in Word 2013 for Windows 10. I'm required to use the IEEE citation style and I want to have my bibliography ordered based on the order with which citations appear in the text.

Therefore, the first citation made in the text should always be labelled [1] - because if I have a citation (X) labelled [1] and I insert a new citation (Y) above it, the (Y) will become [1], and (X) will be updated to [2]. The relevant reordering should also in the Bibliography section.

I've been trying to solve this for a few hours. MS Word 2013 comes with an IEEE citation style but it does not do this.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Try the reference style available from [this webpage](http://heather.sh/2013/02/configuring-automatic-ieee-referencing-in-word-windows-and-os-x/).